# can i make standard wiki pages the default in an enterprise wiki site

Tags: site-template, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki, pages

so I have a subsite that I am working with and it was created (not by me) using the publishing enterprise wiki template. The issue that I have with this is that when I select "add a page" from the site menu (gear icon) it defaults to an enterprise wiki page which has the "last modified on" line, the rating, a place for tags, none of which I want on the page. Most importantly however, it doesn't allow me to restructure the page using the predefined layouts that are available with the standard wiki page.

I've tried to add the standard wiki page to the content types (so I can just set it as the default) but it doesn't seem to be available. Am I missing something? Is the page type labelled as something unintuitive or am I going about this the wrong way?

**Side Note:** For some reason I have two page libraries in the subsite (Site Pages & Pages). One is the default and is fore Enterprise Wiki pages (called Pages) and the other is a for normal pages (the one called Site Pages) but is completely unassociated from the Add a Page option.